# Backbone.js - Pass variable from route to view/collection/model

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, backbone.js

So I'm building a mobile website and I have a directory called 'api' with various php files hat echo JSON formatted data from a remote API. I did this to avoid the cross-domain issue.

But one of the php files needs a GET parameter (i.e. id) so that I can echo the JSON data for a specific object based on it's id.

My collection will need to do this (assuming this will work):

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'models/tournaments/single'
], function(Backbone, singleModel) {
    var TournamentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: singleModel,
        url: '/api/tournament.php?id=' + id,
        parse: function(response) {
            return response;
        }
    });
    return TournamentCollection;
});
```

I have this in my router, but how do I pass the 'id' value to the view or collection:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/home',
    'views/tournament'
], function($, _, Backbone, HomeView, TournamentView) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'home',
            'tournament/:id': 'tournament'
        }
    });

    var initialize = function() {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;

        app_router.on('route:home', function() {
            var homeView = new HomeView();
        });

        app_router.on('route:tournament', function(id) {
            var tournamentView = new TournamentView({id: id});
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking... do you want the collection to fetch the model from the server and then pass it into the view or do you want specifically for the id attribute to be sent? Bit confused as you're already passing it the the `TournamentView`

Comment: How do I read 'id' in the view? I need to send 'id' to the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1) Your definition of the url property of the collection will not work as id is likely not defined when defining the TournamentCollection class. You can use a function rather than a property. TournamentCollection will become something like this:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'models/tournaments/single'
], function(Backbone, singleModel) {
    var TournamentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: singleModel,
        initialize: function (options) {
          this.id = options.id;
        },
        url: function () {
          return '/api/tournament.php?id=' + this.id
        },
        parse: function(response) {
            return response;
        }
    });
    return TournamentCollection;
});
```

This way you can initialize the object with an id, and later, when the url is fetched it will include the correct id.

2) I would probably initialize and fetch the collection from the router. Then from the initialize of the view, listen for that fetch to complete and ultimately re-render the view. Something like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
     'backbone',
     'views/home',
     'views/tournament'
 ], function($, _, Backbone, HomeView, TournamentView) {

     var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
         routes: {
             '': 'home',
             'tournament/:id': 'tournament'
         }
     });

     var initialize = function() {
         var app_router = new AppRouter;

         app_router.on('route:home', function() {
             var homeView = new HomeView();
         });

         app_router.on('route:tournament', function(id) {
             var tournaments = new TournamentCollection({ id: id });
             tournaments.fetch();
             var tournamentView = new TournamentView({ collection: tournaments });
         });

         Backbone.history.start();
     };

     return {
         initialize: initialize
     };
 });

 // Tournament View define stuff
 var TournamentView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function () {
     this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
   },
   render: function () {
     //...
   }
 });
 return TournamentView
```

hope that helps. :)

Comment: I did all this but no luck, this.options is undefined in the collection when calling this.options.id. I read somewhere that I might need to pass the id as an attribute in the constructor, any idea on this?

Comment: `var tournaments = new TournamentCollection({ id: id });` is passing the id in the constructor. there is no this.options.id. There is options.id available in the initialize method of the collection. checkout the route for route:tournament

Comment: I got it working by calling the view inside the success method of `tournaments.fetch()`. I am now struggling to render the new view, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329922/backbone-js-404-jquery-error-on-navigate